# How to Define custom bones for rigify blender?

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

[image]Can we define custom bones for rigify addon blender?

How do we assign "2" rig to "1"

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41058/how-do-i-add-extra-bones-to-nathans-amateur-rigify-and-make-it-as-one)

Comment: Not clear guys. Stuck with the rig. Please explain.

Comment: _"How do we assign "2" rig to "1"_  Now 'm somewhat unclear what you are asking.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have used numbers to to specify the kind of rig in picture. Thanks

Comment: Thankyou,  I'll narrow it down to:. What do you  mean by _"assign"_.   IMO as the question stands at the moment it is a candidate for [closing: unclear what you are asking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)  Perhaps  [this is  more what you had in mind](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44121/how-to-use-the-rigify-building-blocks-for-non-human-rigs)

Comment: I have 2 set of bones; one done in maya and the other in blender. I have some set of animations done in maya with human IK rig. Now I wish to continue  remaining animations in blender with rigify addon with same maya armature. So how do I convert maya human Ik rig to blender meta rig and create Rigify controls and animate.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and try to clarify what it is that you want to do.

Comment: Have a look at re-targetting animation. There is an [addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/97130/15543) designed help with the process. Basically use the animation on rig A to drive rig B with constraints / drivers or other mechanisms. =